# eternal universe vs. creation in greek phillosophy

Tags: universe

I read that Greek philosophers believed in an [eternal universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe#Philosophical_models).

How could they believe in gods creators at the same time?

Comment: Which Greek philosophers? There were quite a few and they didn't agree on many points.

Comment: Which gods as creators? Remember that Zeus and the gods you think of as the Greek gods overthrew other gods (I think they were called the Titans if my memory serves me correct).

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 I don't know which Greek philosophers, but I am sure about even one (see the link).

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I don't think Zeus was the creator but I am adamanted there were some: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_mythology#Literary_sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Timaeus by Plato, gods are created (as entire cosmos) by Demiurge. Demiurge is not creator of world as for example it is in Christianity, but creator of cosmos (Cosmos is harmonically arranged world). Gods are immortals, rationales and almost perfect (almost, because there are created and not eternal). After this, gods by demiurge’s note create other beings, which are mortals, for example human.
But we must note that for most of  Greeks God is form of some particular thing, idea. For example, Eros is love with its purest form. Ares is war and etc.
P.S. In Timaeus it’s also said that there is Creator of the world, but man couldn’t have knowledge about it, so it brings other concept which is Demiurge.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very obvious, they were **different** philosophers!  **One** philosopher could believe in an "eternal universe," **and a different**  philosopher could believe in "gods creators."

Comment: That seems to be the answer but are you sure about it? Only small percent of ancient Greeks were atheists but eternal universe is the very common philosophy.